# Chrome SVG nested in Button has size 0x0

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, button, sass

I'm facing a problem where I can't seem to nest an svg component inside a button element. The size of the svg always falls to 0x0. The expected behavior would be, that the svg takes up as much space as it needs. This behavior works fine in Firefox but **not Chrome**. In despair I tried adding the `width: auto;` and `height: auto;` property to the svg but that didn't change anything.

```html
<button class="form--btn form--btn__icon ">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
        <path d="M34.52 239.03L228.87 44.69c9.37-9.37 24.57-9.37 33.94 
        0l22.67 22.67c9.36 9.36 9.37 24.52.04 33.9L131.49 256l154.02 
        154.75c9.34 9.38 9.32 24.54-.04 33.9l-22.67 22.67c-9.37 9.37-24.57 
        9.37-33.94 0L34.52 272.97c-9.37-9.37-9.37-24.57 0-33.94z"/>
    </svg>
</button>
```

The corresponding scss:

```
.form--btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;

    &__icon svg {
        fill: currentColor;
    }
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/asdf1414/pen/wvpQPdZ

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

~ asdf1414

Comment: neither the button nore the svg element has a width. An svg element without a width and/or height will take all the width available which in this case is 0

Comment: I suppose there is no possibility to let the svg expand as much as it can without setting a specific width/height to neither the button nor the svg itself?

Comment: You are wright. You will need a width or a height or both for at least one of them (button or svg).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height of the SVG:

```css
.form--btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.form--btn__icon svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button class="form--btn form--btn__icon ">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
    <path d="M34.52 239.03L228.87 44.69c9.37-9.37 24.57-9.37 33.94 
      0l22.67 22.67c9.36 9.36 9.37 24.52.04 33.9L131.49 256l154.02 
      154.75c9.34 9.38 9.32 24.54-.04 33.9l-22.67 22.67c-9.37 9.37-24.57 
      9.37-33.94 0L34.52 272.97c-9.37-9.37-9.37-24.57 0-33.94z"/>
  </svg>
</button>
```